# Husky: cannot spawn .husky/commit-msg: No such file or directory

Tags: git, hook, githooks, husky, git-husky

I have been working with husky for few years now. We started a new project and was sure to add husky for pre-commit and commit-msg linting. But this time we faced some issue in the windows machine.

We configured the husky in the project using a mac. When we added new dev who has a windows machine, there was error in commiting.

we have,

- pre-commit
- commit-msg

`.husky/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

`.husky/commit-msg`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(dirname "$0")
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx --no-install commitlint --edit $1
```

`.husky/_/husky.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
if [ -z "$husky_skip_init" ]; then
  debug () {
    if [ "$HUSKY_DEBUG" = "1" ]; then
      echo "husky (debug) - $1"
    fi
  }

  readonly hook_name="$(basename -- "$0")"
  debug "starting $hook_name..."

  if [ "$HUSKY" = "0" ]; then
    debug "HUSKY env variable is set to 0, skipping hook"
    exit 0
  fi

  if [ -f ~/.huskyrc ]; then
    debug "sourcing ~/.huskyrc"
    . ~/.huskyrc
  fi

  readonly husky_skip_init=1
  export husky_skip_init
  sh -e "$0" "$@"
  exitCode="$?"

  if [ $exitCode != 0 ]; then
    echo "husky - $hook_name hook exited with code $exitCode (error)"
  fi

  if [ $exitCode = 127 ]; then
    echo "husky - command not found in PATH=$PATH"
  fi

  exit $exitCode
fi
```

files inside the `.husky` folder.
the pre-commit file works just fine without any issue.
but we get following error in case of commit-msg

**`error: cannot spawn .husky/commit-msg: No such file or directory`**

it is not even getting invoked.

does anyone encountered this issue ? Is there any fix for this?

**NB : Please don't suggest `--no-verify` as it does the opposite of what we are trying to implement.**

Answer (score 1):

I lost two day trying to fix this issue. The solution is very simple.

Solution :

**Removed the empty line at the beginning in `.husky/commit-msg`.**